# Removing .php extension in .htaccess in conjunction with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file-extension, wp-admin

I have a static website running in conjunction with wordpress in the same directory. It all works fine. For the static pages that don't use wordpress I can remove the .php file extensions by adding these rules to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However it broke /wp-admin/. Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/$` before the `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!